# Управление профилями кеша Redis

Tags: golang, redis

Реализовав кеширование данных в Redis, столкнулся со следующим.

На хосте разработки расположено большое количество тестовых данных. Определенные данные кешируются для использования микросервисами, запущенными на нем.

Эти же микросервисы используются для обработки данных, расположенных на другом, "продуктовом" хосте (продуктовый сервер - это достаточно старый NAS *Synology* с проблемами развертывания ноды Redis на нем с помощью iPkg или других средств).

Таким образом, работая с двумя категориями данных, я должен иметь возможность "переключать" кеши с dev на product.

Если считать, что кеш - это те же данные, которые могут храниться в БД, более надежной, но и более "медленной", для меня необходим сценарий запуска системы с удалением одного набора кеша и импортом из БД в Redis другого. При завершении работы системы (не работает круглосуточно, проект для домашнего потребления) кеш Redis необходимо выгрузить и сохранить в иную БД (в моем случае это *PostgreSQL*).

Все это выглядит как скрипт с набором опеределенных операций и наверняка вопрос серилизации кеша решался другими.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как. Потому что работать с файлом `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` напрямую или с помощью *rdiff-backup* и как [здесь](https://avinton.com/en/academy/loading-data-postgresql-redis/) для загрузки кеша на Redis мне кажется не самым лучшим решением.

Конечно, еще вопрос можно решить настройками имен хранимых в кеше структур. Но, все же, возможность сохранения копии кеша в более надежную БД как PostgreSQL мне кажется неплохой идеей, потому что формируемые данные кеша - это продукт в том числе ручной деятельности, на которое тратится значительное время.

P.S. Нашел также плагин [FDW for PostgreSQL 9.1+](https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw#redis-fdw-for-postgresql-91), который, если я правильно понял, способен взаимодействовать с Redis, но удастся ли собрать его на NAS - пока неизвестно.

Answer (score 0):

Кеш для того и создан, чтобы хранить там данные, которые потерять не жалко, так как их всегда можно закешировать снова.

Если у вас возникло желание и требования по сохранению кеша в надежной БД postgres, значит у вас неверная архитектура приложения.

Редис свой дамп сбрасывает 1 раз в определнный промежуток времени, который указан в настройках редиса. Сохраняйте этот дамп например по крону, чтобы вы могли его использовать на локальной машине или для восстановления данных.

То что вы не нашли такой информации по переносу данных из редиса в postgres как раз и говорит о том, что такие задачи никто не решает. Так как это разные хранилища редис это key value, а Postgres реляционное.

И так как на проде и на деве обычно разные данные, то и кеш у них разный, и копировать кеш с прода на дев и обратно нет смысла